# Integral of $x/(2x-1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm not sure how to do this, I'm also new to math.stackexchange so please excuse any novice mistakes. So anyways, here is a question I have on a summer assignment for Calculus BC (this is review from AB).

Find: 
$$\int {x\over(2x-1)} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: $\frac{x}{2x-1}=\frac12 \frac{2x-1+1}{2x-1}=\frac12\left(1+\frac{1}{2x-1}\right)$.  Does that help?

Comment: yeah, thanks! Oh and whoever downvoted me for being a novice, please don't

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And I was not the "down voter."  I'll up vote to neutralize.

Comment: @Kemosabe Next time expand on your thoughts about the problem and show any work you've done

Comment: oooh ok I think I understand now, it's just like stack overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \frac{x}{2x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac12 \cdot \frac{2x-1+1}{2x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x= \frac{1}{2} \int 1+\frac{1}{2x-1}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

So we get $$\int \frac{x}{2x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \left(x + \frac{1}{2} \ln{|2x-1|}\right) + \mathrm{c}$$

Comment: What you wrote is true if $2x - 1 > 0$.  In general, $$\int \frac{1}{2x - 1} dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln |2x - 1| + C$$

Comment: @Taussig Fixed, thanks! Forgot the mod.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y = 2x-1$.  Then $x = \tfrac{y+1}{2}$, and $\tfrac{dy}{dx} = 2$.  Then

$$\int_{a}^b \frac{x}{2x-1} dx = 
\int_{\frac{a+1}{2}}^{\frac{b+1}2} \frac{\frac{y+1}{2}}y \frac{dy}{2} = 
\frac 14 \int_{\frac{a+1}{2}}^{\frac{b+1}2} \frac{y+1}y dy = 
\frac 14 \int_{\frac{a+1}{2}}^{\frac{b+1}2} 1 + \frac 1y dy.$$